# The new added field doesn’t show up when I reload the page

Tags: javascript

I am facing an issue and I don’t know how to resolve it.
I added a field on a webpage using JavaScript, ( when the user clicks on a button a new field should be added and it must be a static I mean it doesn’t suppose to be disappeared when move to another page or refreshing the page)the field appears but when I refresh the page it disappears.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: you lose the state when the page refreshes, so you need to save the state in storage location like session/localstorage/cookies

Comment: [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) in order to keep data between pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the local variables which are set by JS will be cleared when refreshing page, so what you can do is,

1) make use of [LocalStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or

2) if you have a server, create some API calls, store the value in DB, if the user logs in from different browser, he can see the field.